Why is the first-order singular term allowed in the $T(w)T(z)$ OPE?
In CFT, the OPE of $T(w)T(x)$ is determined to be:
$$ T(w)T(z) = \frac{c/2}{(w-z)^4}+\frac{2T(z)}{(w-z)^2} +\frac{\partial T(z)}{w-z}+reg. $$
The $(w-z)^{-3}$ term's omission is justified in the sources I've seen by demanding that interchanging $w$ and $z$ should give the same result (a condition I am not 100% sure why it should necessarily apply). But I don't quite understand why this shouldn't also apply to the $(w-z)^{-1}$ term. Obviously that term has to be there in order for this tensor to transform the way we want, I just don't understand how this eludes this symmetry argument for omitting $(w-z)^{-3}$.

Which sources? Which pages?

The original BPZ paper, Ginsparg's lecture notes, diFrancesco, some lectures I saw by Cachazo on 2D CFT on Youtube, plenty of stuff. Everywhere I've seen where they derive the OPE for T(z)T(w) (which is most introductory stuff on CFT) does it more or less the same way.

I was wrong, BPZ does not justify it at all. Ginsparg does say that the 4th order term is permitted by "Bose symmetry".

Have you actually tried the calculation to see what you get? It is absolutely allowed by symmetry and you’d see it immediately if you just work it out.

@Prahar, I was more confused about the fact that the other odd-order term is argued to vanish, while this clearly doesn't vanish. I was also not sure how to correctly work it out, but I figured it out after Qmechanic's answer.


Note that if we Taylor expand the $TT$ OPE
$$(z\leftrightarrow w)~=~ {\cal R}[T(w)T(z)]~=~\frac{c/2}{(w-z)^4}+\frac{2T(\frac{w+z}{2})}{(w-z)^2} +{\rm reg}. \tag{S}$$
around the symmetric point $\frac{w+z}{2}$, there cannot be odd-order terms by symmetry. (Here the symbol ${\cal R}$ denotes radial operator ordering.)

If we next Taylor expand the above OPE (S) around a non-symmetric point $z$, then the third-order singular term $(w-z)^{-3}$ remains absent, while the first-order singular term $(w-z)^{-1}$ natural appears.


